# Logic after Response.Write() in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, response.write

I have a webpage that has to respond very quickly to each client, as many requests will be made to the page. I am using `Response.Write(data)` to write the data that is generated back to the client.

But this is where I want the flow of data to *stop*, per se. I have logic after the `Response.Write()` statement, but I want the client to have received the data from `Response.Write()` before this code executes; I do not want this code to hold up the client, as I am running some SQL queries in a few cases.

My initial thought is to spawn a new thread to handle the logic, but are there any caveats to new threads from a website? A new thread would continue processing while the data flow would effectively be "stopped" as stated above, correct? Is there a better way to address my problem?

Comment: have you tested the existing logic under load to determine whether this level of effort is necessary? a really famous computer guy once stated that premature optimization is the root of all evil. Anyways, consider using built in caching of pages and data if you can, or use AJAX or json webservices, load the fast content, and asynchronously load the slow data.

Comment: The client is just requesting very quick data; it is not a browser with a javascript engine. To your point about premature optimization, I would normally agree, except that scalability is a very near concern. There shouldn't be any issues with less than 10 clients, but if there are 100 or 1000 clients connected, I'm confident this would be a large bottleneck.